# Reversing a linked list issue

Tags: python, linked-list

I am trying to reverse a linked and this is my implementation:

```
import copy
# ...

def reverse(linked_list):
    """
    Reverse the inputted linked list

    Args:
       linked_list(obj): Linked List to be reversed
    Returns:
       obj: Reveresed Linked List
    """

    if linked_list.head is None:
        return linked_list

    copy_list = copy.copy(linked_list)

    current = copy_list.head
    while current.next is not None:
        new_head = current.next
        tail = current.next.next
        new_head.next = copy_list.head
        current.next = tail
        copy_list.head = new_head

    return copy_list
```

Consider that the list is populated like this:

```
myList = LinkedList()
for value in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]:
    myList.append(value)

# myList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

so `myList` now contains: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` - so far so good..

but then I reverse it:

```
reversed = reverse(myList) 

# reversed = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
# myList = [1]
```

and the result is that `reversed` indeed contains a reversed list `[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]`, but as a side effect this changes the contents of `myList` to: `[1]`.

So it looks like whenever I am reversing the list, instead of working with a copy of it, I am changing the original list too.
Not sure why because I explicitly create a copy `copy_list = copy.copy(linked_list)` and then base my work on it.

Would appreciate if you could give me hint.

**PS: I know that similar questions have been asked before, but I am not interested in a general solution, I am interested more in finding out what's wrong in my implementation.**

Additional classes:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None


class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def append(self, value):
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = Node(value)
            return

        node = self.head
        while node.next:
            node = node.next

        node.next = Node(value)

    def __iter__(self):
        node = self.head
        while node:
            yield node.value
            node = node.next

    def __repr__(self):
        return str([v for v in self])
```

Comment: "copy" creates a shallow copy (contained objects like the linked list nodes aren't copied). Try "deepcopy" instead.

Comment: Amazing, thank you very much @MichaelButscher. This solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would tell you the short answer,
You are using copy library which has two options

1. Shallow copy
2. Deepcopy

copy.copy uses shallow copy which uses pass by reference and the changes done in the copied file will also affect the original.

copy.deepcopy creates a new structure where the changes in the new file would not affect 
the original.